# increment var in gnu parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

How can I use an increment variable within `parallel`? Note the **`$int` variable** in the output filename (prefix). I realize order can change, and that is fine, but what's useful is to have integers prefixing the output for downstream work (the length of `${array[@]}` changes).

I'm trying to convert this for-loop into a nice parallel cmd to run on a cluster. One feature I really like is to have this process quit if any of the jobs have a non-zero exit status described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Termination

**From:**

```
var='infile.txt'
int=1
for file in ${array[@]}; do
  script.rb -i $var -o $int_$file
  ((int+=1))
done
```

**To:**

```
parallel --halt soon,fail=1 --jobs $NSLOTS script.sh -i $var -o int_{} ::: ${array[@]}
```

I was thinking something like a {1..array_len} construct might work to act as a counter but this doesn't: `parallel --halt soon,fail=1 --jobs $NSLOTS script.sh -i $var -o {2}_{1} :::: ${array[@]} {1..${#array[@]}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
parallel --halt soon,fail=1 script.rb -i $var -o {#}_{} ::: ${array[@]}
```

where `{#}` is the job sequence number.

---

Here is a simple example:

```
parallel -k echo "param="{} ",sequence="{#} ::: 2 4 6 8

param=2 ,sequence=1
param=4 ,sequence=2
param=6 ,sequence=3
param=8 ,sequence=4
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Replacement-strings explains this but I didn't understand it's use as a counter, thank you!